# Caching in Rails (2.1) without too much logic in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I recently got into page/fragment caching in Rails (thanks to [Railscast #90](http://railscasts.com/episodes/90-fragment-caching)). But as I tried out myself it made my view much uglier.

The examples that I've found on the internet in most cases just cached a simple query of entities (mostly something like, "most_recent_products"

But when I start to cache a user profile with the user's latest articles (simple blog example) it gets messy real quick.

Example

show.html.erb:

```
# some code
<% cache "user#{params[:id]}" do %>
<div id="user">
  <h2>Product.find(params[:id])</h2>
  <ul>
  <% for article in Articles.find_by_user(Product.find(params[:id])) %>
    <li><%= link_to h(article), article %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
# some code
```

If I don't want to do a single database query (when cached), this is the way to go (all the queries must go inside the cache block).

I understand that you can simplify this by partials, or store it in a variable but still as soon as there is more than one entity involved, you need to execute a lot of logic in the view.

Isn't there a better way to load all the variables you need (@user, @articles) somewhere else, but only fill them when needed (and I don't like to check the cache in the controller)